# Sign in with apple react native issue

Tags: react-native, npm

Please suggest Working Library For Apple sign in React-Native. I have tried below npm
1) react-native-apple-authentication.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Were you able to integrate Apple-SignIn. if yes then how? Your help would be much appreciated..

Comment: Apple-SignIn done using Bridge in iOS

Comment: So, you wrote your own, bridge between native and RN. right?.